# How do we effectively prevent concurrent use of a web-application in one session?

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc

We have built a Spring MVC web application that is heavily relying on the user to do things in a certain order, and while it prevents users from circumventing this (without trying very hard) in the usual case (by not offering options to “go to places” you’re not supposed to at the given moment), we’re having some problems when people open another instance of the application in a new tab or browser window.

Since the application stores the domain model in the user’s session, using the program in another window can potentially mess up the model’s data, we’ve already implemented a page-ID mechanism that validates the user using the program in the correct order and not using the browser navigation, but we’re still facing problems when things like resetting the program (this is a feature, redirecting the user to the home screen and clearing the domain model) happen in one window and the user then tries to do something relying on the domain model to be filled with valid data in another window (leading to a NullPointerException quite quickly).

Comment: You shouldn't relying on a user. First checks the user rights on the server side before proceeding to any active operations either. And do not forget to catch exceptions and check the necessary objects on **null**. It'll make your application more robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ever reads this question again:

Instead of the HttpSession keeping exactly one copy of the domain model it now holds a collection and we transport a reference to a single one of the models through the requests/responses so we can get the right model to work on in our controllers and views.

Answer (score 0):

Storing some user details (like id, name, email) in a session might be ok, but storing the user's **state** (or any data that changes often and/or significantly affects other things in your app) doesn't sound like a good idea.

Hopefully one of the following approaches will fit you:

- Don't save state in the session - load it from the database whenever you need it (in your case, whenever the user tries to access one of the steps that should be done in order). If you use caching, this shouldn't have major performance consequences.
- Don't save state in the database, only in the session - works for limited cases (for instance, ordering airline tickets) where you can postpone committing your domain object until the process has finished.
- Use Ajax for multi-step processes and don't save state at all (except implicitly in the browser). This requires putting all the steps into one page and ajaxifying some of your code.

Regardless, if someone logs in and tries to go to step 3, they shouldn't get an exception thrown at them, but that's a different story.

Comment: A thing I forgot to mention in my OP is: the session is the only thing we can use to identify the user as we do not require a unique login. There is authentication, but many users (as in actual persons) will use a single user (as in technical account) by design.
As I see it storing the state in a different place would then just relocate the core problem to a different place, or am I thinking wrong here?
Your 3rd point sounds interesting though! I'll have to have a look at how feasible this fits into our current architecture.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd let user to wander around other parts of the website - the parts that don't interfere with your wizard process. However, once they try to restart it - check if there's PageID in session, and remind them they have not finished what they started, and ask if they would like to cancel/restart or continue on from where they left it.